What is the two-dot notation in Lean 4?
I saw a new notation consisting of two dots .. as in the map_zero .. line in the following (from Mathematics in Lean):
def mkVectorSpace {K X : Type*} [Field K] [AddCommGroup X] (ρ : K →+* AddMonoid.End X) : Module K X where
  smul a x := ρ a x
  one_smul x := show ρ 1 x = x by simp
  mul_smul a b x := show ρ (a * b) _ = _ by rw [map_mul]; rfl
  smul_zero x := map_zero ..
  smul_add a x y := map_add ..
  add_smul a b x := show ρ (a + b) _ = _ by rw [map_add]; rfl
  zero_smul x := show ρ 0 _ = _ by simp

I couldn't find out what the .. means in the text or on internet search. Hovering the mouse over it shows (ρ x) 0 = 0, but the content changes with context. Replacing the .. with a placeholder _ seems to be OK. And there is no definition for it to go to in VSCode.
The question is:
What does the two dot notation mean, and how should one use it?

This syntactic sugar creates as many holes as needed to fill in the arguments.  For instance, if you have a function f : A → B → C, f .. will elaborate to f _ _ (which in turn will try to synthesize actual arguments in place of these holes).  This plays nicely with named arguments, and regular argument application, so you can do the following, for instance:
example (f : Nat → (A : Type) → (a : A) → (B : Type) → (eq : A = B) → Nat) : Nat :=
  f 3 (a := "hello") (eq := rfl) ..

Unfortunately, AFAIK, this is only documented in the source code.
The same notation can be used in match patterns, ie.
match x with
| some .. => ()
| none => ()

and with the structure syntax:
structure A where
  a : Nat
  b : Bool
  c : Unit

example (a : A) : Bool :=
  let { b, .. } := a
  b

